# Does anyone know where to get the XSD file describing the junitReport.xml file format expected by Hudson?

Tags: xsd, hudson, report

I need the XSD of junitReport.xml recognized by Hudson.

Does anyone know where can it be found?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've create a [junit.xsd](http://windyroad.org/2011/02/07/apache-ant-junit-xml-schema/) for [Ant's `junit` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html). It was created by examining the relevant Java code in Ant 1.8.2

Comment: JFYI: there is actually a schema available here: [surefire-test-report.xsd](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/maven-surefire-plugin/src/site/resources/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd). It comes from a `maven-surefire-plugin`, but AFAIK reports produced by Ant and Maven are identical.

Answer (score 2):

At [this link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/200902.mbox/<dffc72020902241548l4316d645w2e98caf5f0aac770@mail.gmail.com>), someone has already tried to analyse the JUnit code to check for any references for it's XML schema. But an XSD is no requirement to create XML and apparently, it doesn't use one.