# Where can i find the DTD or XML Schema of surefire generated XML (TEST-<testname>.xml) file?

Tags: maven-2, automated-tests, maven, surefire

Where can i find the DTD or XML Schema of surefire generated XML (TEST-.xml) file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I* think that Maven is using the XML result format "owned" by Ant and *I* am not sure there is an official DTD or Schema. From [JUnit 4 XML schematized?](http://old.nabble.com/JUnit-4-XML-schematized--td13946472.html) on the JUnit-user list:

> > There's a pretty standard format for JUnit XML output. You've
> >      probably seen it: there's a `<testsuite>` root element containing
> >      zero-or-more `<testcase>` elements, each of which may contain a
> >      `<failure>` or `<error>` element. (There's also a `<properties>` element
> >      with zero-or-more `<property>` elements.) A lot of tools know how to
> >      read this format and report on it, including at least Ant, Maven,
> >      Cruise Control, Hudson, Bamboo, Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA.
> >
> > Is this XML standardized anywhere in a DTD or XML Schema or something?
> >
> > If there isn't a standard, could we go about making a standard and
> >      blessing it? (Perhaps JUnit 4.5 could include an XMLReporter that
> >      could be a reference implementation.)
> >
> > In particular, I'm curious to know how one would represent that a test
> >      has been ignored in "standard" JUnit XML.
>
> I never found such a "standard". And
>   imo it is a good idea as you may
>   enhance the report by using your own
>   information and still have the tools
>   working. But if you go with a
>   DTD/schema and validation then this
>   will stop working.

#### See also

- [JUnit 4 XML schematized?](http://old.nabble.com/JUnit-4-XML-schematized--td13946472.html) on the JUnit-user list
- [schema for junit xml output](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/200902.mbox/%3Cdffc72020902241548l4316d645w2e98caf5f0aac770@mail.gmail.com%3E) on the ant-dev list

#### Related questions

- [Does anyone know where to get the XSD file describing the junitReport.xml file format expected by Hudson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385499/does-anyone-know-where-to-get-the-xsd-file-describing-the-junitreport-xml-file-fo)
- [Spec. for JUnit XML Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442556/spec-for-junit-xml-output)

Comment: Just a heads-up that the `old.nabble.com` references in your:  [JUnit 4 XML schematized?](http://old.nabble.com) web links appear to have gone stale. I was just going to fix them for you, but after running through 4 pages of Google search results, without finding a definitive link update, the **do no harm** approach seemed best.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is 6 years old, but just for future readers...

Actually there is an official schema for surefire generated XML - it can be found here: [surefire-test-report.xsd](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report-3.0.xsd).

Comment: Thank you! This should now become the accepted answer, I think.